# Is there an empty Jquery selector?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that I can default to some kind of empty selector so that I can still call custom jQuery functions on it, but in those functions I can just check if it's valid.

I know I can check if the selector is valid before I make the function call but I would rather handle that in the functions once so that my code looks cleaner and I don't have to keep remembering to check it for additional function calls.

Say I have the following...

```
$.fn.Foo = function() { ... });

var $selector = someVariable != null ? $('# + someVariable') : emptySelector???
```

This way I could do...

```
$selector.Foo();
```

And in my function I could just check if it's valid...

```
$.fn.Foo = function() { 

     if ($(this) is a valid selector)
       // execute the code

});
```

I am new to jQuery so maybe I am thinking the wrong way. Is they any way to do this so I don't get errors saying I can't call the function on an invalid object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$()` will return an empty jQuery object with no elements.

If your function only calls other jQuery methods like `each()`, you don't need any special handling; those methods will not do anything if there aren't any elements.

If you have other logic, check `this.length`.

Comment: Thanks man. I was looking for exactly this. My google searches must have been way off.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the length of what jQuery returns.

```
var $mightExist= $('.might-exist');
if ($mightExist.length > 0) {
  // It exists!
}
```

Comment: Right, but I was hoping to leave the function calls in place regardless of if it exists or not. Depending on the state of my app, the variables used for fetching selectors might not have any values.